coreapp bootstrap is failing after main is moved to bazel
When running bootstrap the job fails for below
sdb-ant-failure-listener-operation-start: parseserverid:183707999:target:1
Adding execute permission to /home/sfdc/salesforce/bazel-bin/db/tools/db_tools_wrapper_command
Executing SdbBootstrapServerIdParser with /home/sfdc/salesforce/bazel-bin/db/tools/db_tools_wrapper_command --singlejar
Caught exception: exec returned: 1
Caught exception: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/sfdc/salesforce/build/build-bazel.xml:351: Failed to run execute-bazel-binary SdbBootstrapServerIdParser. The error is: exec returned: 1
sdb-ant-failure-listener-operation-end: parseserverid:183707999:target:1
sdb-ant-failure-listener-operation-end: sdb.schemabootstrap:1458751976:target:1
We ran the spinnaker casam bootstrap job and it fails for the above error
https://ui.spinnaker2.sfcd.deploy2.aws-esvc3-uswest2.aws.sfdc.cl/#/applications/casaminternal/executions?q=sdb29&pipeline=bootstrap-v1-test1-uswest2-core4-sdb29-sdb29-coreapp-latest
